# how to set NSGradient to NSWindow background

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow, nsgradient

I am new to cocoa I am try to set `NSGradient` to the `NSWindow` background but it's too difficult for me...I have try this code

```
NSGradient *gradient = [[NSGradient alloc] initWithStartingColor:[NSColor orangeColor] endingColor:[NSColor lightGrayColor]];
NSRect windowFrame = [self frame];
[gradient drawInRect:windowFrame angle:90];
```

but it is not working.... any other way to set `NSGradient` to `NSWindow`....

Comment: In which method do you have this code? Should be in `-drawRect:`

Comment: yes I have used in - (void)drawRect method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can do it by subclassing `NSWindow`'s View.**

Create new window view's class (For example with title WindowViewSubclass).

Then **.h** file should look like this:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface WindowViewSubclass : NSView {

}

@end
```

and **.m** file:

```
#import "WindowViewSubclass.h"

@implementation WindowViewSubclass

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    NSGradient *gradient = [[NSGradient alloc] initWithStartingColor:[NSColor orangeColor] endingColor:[NSColor lightGrayColor]];
    NSRect windowFrame = [self frame];
    [gradient drawInRect:windowFrame angle:90];
}

@end
```

Now select window's view and go to Identity Inspectory -> Custom Class -> and select class like this:

[image: Screenshot]

**Result:**

[image: Result image]

Comment: It is working for Window View only... but i need to set Gradient to NSWindow title bar...

Comment: I have subclassed the NSWindow but the above code is not working to set gradient to  NSWindow title bar

Comment: @navinsillu if You want to change title bar color You need to use borderlessWindow mask and create titlebar by yourself.